# How to handle configuration changes while working with Jetpack compose and Kotlin flows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I've been working with flows and jetpack compose, I've been trying to fix it for the past day. I've gone through a few articles, and everything works as expected unless the device is rotated or switched to dark mode. I've placed the actual flow stuff in the viewmodel and fetched it from the composable function with `.collectAsState()`; I've also tried with `.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`, which kind of collects the flow's data with life-cycle awareness (it's still *experimental*). But the problem still remains.

At this point:

in `HomeScreenViewModel.kt`

```
val issLocationFromAPIFlow = mutableStateOf<Flow<ISSLocationDTO>>(emptyFlow())
...
init{
  viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default + coroutineExceptionalHandler) {
     val issLocationData = async { issLocationFetching.getISSLatitudeAndLongitude() }
     issLocationFromAPIFlow.value = issLocationData.await()
  }
}
```

in `Composable.kt`

```
@Composable
fun ISSData() {
val homeScreenViewModel: HomeScreenViewModel = viewModel()

val issLatitude = homeScreenViewModel.issLocationFromAPIFlow.value.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(
        initialValue = ISSLocationDTO(IssPosition("", ""), "", 0)
    ).value.iss_position.latitude

    Text(text = issLatitude, color = AppTheme.colors.primary)
}
```

- This works as expected. If I didn't change it to dark mode or rotate the device, but at some point when I rotate or switch to dark mode, the value falls to null, and it just can't handle it, even though I've placed an actual data source in the viewmodel.
- I read [this](https://medium.com/proandroiddev/how-to-collect-flows-lifecycle-aware-in-jetpack-compose-babd53582d0b) article, which mentions storing the flow from the viewmodel and a local lifecycle owner [`LocalLifecycleOwner`] as a key in `remember`, as far as I know, that `remember` avoids recomposition and sort of caches and returns the cached value from variables or whatever, but in my case, I want the newly updated data through the flow, which should handle device configuration changes.

Screen recordings of :

- [while rotating the device](https://www.dropbox.com/s/utnn8ut8x0p67zi/VID_20221110194416.mp4?dl=0)
- [while switching to dark theme or vice-versa](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hi9ojryhs3zpbv7/VID_20221110201533.mp4?dl=0)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simplify little bit like:

```
val issLocationFromAPIFlow : Flow<ISSLocationDTO>> = 
    issLocationFetching.getISSLatitudeAndLongitude()
    .onStart{
         emit(ISSLocationDTO(IssPosition("", ""), "", 0))
   }.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)

...
init{}
```

then

```
val homeScreenViewModel: HomeScreenViewModel = viewModel()

val issLatitude = homeScreenViewModel.issLocationFromAPIFlow
.collectAsState(null).value?.iss_position?.latitude
```

make sure that `issLocationFetching.getISSLatitudeAndLongitude()` is not a suspending function, it should just return a flow

Comment: Still the same issue, value doesn't get updated and falls to null after configuration changes from the VM itself (I've checked through logs) :(